# Cant find route /releases/add

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongodb, express

I have an CRUD application where you can create releases.
A user can add a release (release has a version and description)
This is done by a button and some fields where you can input the details

```
    <button (click)="addRelease(version.value, description.value)" [disabled]="angForm.pristine || angForm.invalid" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
```

My addRelease function:

```
    addRelease(version, description) {
this.releaseservice.addRelease(version, description);
}
```

My addRelease function in my service:

```
    addRelease(version,description) {
const uri = 'http://localhost:4000/releases/add';
const obj = {
  version: version,
  description: description
};
this
  .http
  .post(uri, obj)
  .subscribe(res =>
      console.log('Done'));
}
```

Then in my releaseRoutes.js

```
   releaseRoutes.route('/releases/add').post(function (req, res) {
   var release = new Release(req.body);
   release.save()
   .then(item => {
   res.status(200).json({'release': 'release added successfully'});
   })
   .catch(err => {
   res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
    });
   });
```

server.js:

```
   releaseRoutes = require('./expressRoutes/releaseRoutes')
   const app = express();
   app.use('/releases', releaseRoutes);
```

Some code is omitted to make it easier to read.

When I try to create a new release
it gives 404 error

```
    POST http://localhost:4000/releases/add 404 (Not Found)
   core.js:1449 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404,statusText: "Not Found", url: "http://localhost:4000/releases/add", ok: false, …}
```

I'm new to this and need some help on resolving this error, been stuck with it for a couple of days

Comment: Are you sure your server is running on port 4000?

Comment: Try changing `releaseRoutes.route('/releases/add')` to `releaseRoutes.route('/add')`

Comment: That does the trick :) thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already defined the route for `/releases` in `app.use('/releases', releaseRoutes);`

Change `releaseRoutes.route('/releases/add')` to `releaseRoutes.route('/add')`